# Turi Create - stuck at “Starting brute force nearest neighbors model training”

Tags: machine-learning, nearest-neighbor, turi-create

I’m following Turi Create tutorial on Image Similarity
https://apple.github.io/turicreate/docs/userguide/image_similarity/

I got stuck at:
Starting brute force nearest neighbors model training.
In [ ]:

Its been 14 hours already, tried 2 times and it always get stuck at this point.

Any clue what is wrong?

[image]